# How to set a data of X Axis and Y Axis in MPAndroid Chart Dynamically

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me How to set a Data to a Line Chart Dynamically with Different Data Points?

My Code ->

```
try {
 for (int u = 0; u < dataList.size(); u++) {
  Log.e("Data_List_Size", dataList.size() + "");
  for (int j = 0; j < trafficFilter.dataPoints.size(); j++) {
   yVals.add(new Entry(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(u).getY(), u));
   xVals.add(String.valueOf(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getX()));
  }
  set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
  dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is well described in their sample app.

Answer (score 0):

For BarChart Create A List and Add your Data like this ->

```
List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 30f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 80f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 60f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 50f)); 
                                    // gap of 2f
entries.add(new BarEntry(5f, 70f));
entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 60f));

BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
```

For Other Charts procedure is same just use different object for different type of graphs. See [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data) more information.

Your whole Code be like this ->

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // in this example, a LineChart is initialized from xml
    LineChart chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);

    //  Adding Data to show it inside the Graph..
    EntryClass entryClass = new EntryClass();

    for (int u = 0; u < dataList.size(); u++) {
        Log.e("Data_List_Size", dataList.size() + "");
        for (int j = 0; j < trafficFilter.dataPoints.size(); j++) {
            entryClass.AddintoList(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getX(),trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(u).getY(), u));
        }
    }

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entryClass.getEntryList(),"Sample Data");
    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    chart.setData(lineData);
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

This is how your EntryClass should look like ->

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EntryClass {
    private List<Entry> entryList;

    EntryClass(){
        entryList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntryList() {
        return entryList;
    }

    public void AddintoList(float X,float Y) {
        entryList.add(new Entry(X,Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: i am still not getting please share Full Source Code

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, I have edited my full answer, showing how to add data and how to set it up on the chart as well.

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, what do you mean by dynamically? This is the dynamic way. do you want to add list inside the XYData?

Comment: get the data from Server and Add Multiple Line on y Axis with Common Values in X Axis and Multiple list in XY Values

Comment: Whats the type of data you are getting from server?

Comment: get a x and y Values this is my Complete Code

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, can you upload your source code so that i can understand the situation?

Comment: for (int u = 0; u < dataList.size(); u++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < trafficFilter.dataPoints.size(); j++) {
 yVals.add(new Entry(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(u).getY(), u));
               xVals.add(String.valueOf(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getX()));
   }
 set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
  dataSets.add(set1);// add the datasets
  LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
 mChart.setData(data);  }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Set_Data_Exception", e + "");
        }
    }

Comment: try {
            for (int u = 0; u < dataList.size(); u++) {
                Log.e("Data_List_Size", dataList.size() + "");
                for (int j = 0; j < trafficFilter.dataPoints.size(); j++) {
                    yVals.add(new Entry(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(u).getY(), u));
                    xVals.add(String.valueOf(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getX()));
                }

                set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
                dataSets.add(set1);// add the datasets

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, Edit your question and put your code there not in comments.

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, I have updated my code according to your requirement please check that out. just don't forgot to convert/cast data into float when passing inside addintolist function.

Comment: private void setData() {
        try {
for (int u = 0; u < dataList.size(); u++) {
   Log.e("Data_List_Size", dataList.size() + "");
entryClass.AddintoList(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getX(), trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(u).getY(), u);
   }
            }
  set1 = new LineDataSet(entryClass.getEntryList(), "Sample Data");
dataSets.add(set1);// add the datasets
 LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
 mChart.setData(data); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Set_Data_Exception", e + "");
        }
    }

Comment: set1 = new LineDataSet(entryClass.getEntryList(), "Sample Data");
//            dataSets.add(set1);// add the datasets
            LineData data = new LineData(set1);
Cannot Resolve Constructor

Comment: @RiteshKanugo, Dont post your code here, you need to know about that, also post your whole question with appropriate code in Question itself. Your question is not clear as well.

Comment: can any tell me how to set a Real Time Data on Multi Points in Graph View